# Show data in more than 10 columns in listbox

Tags: excel, vba

I have userform containing 20 textbox and one listbox.

The  code should show  data in listbox after filling 20 textbox.

I searched the internet where I found this  code which works for somebody but not for me.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim arr1 As Variant
arr1 = Array(Me.TextBox1, Me.TextBox2, Me.TextBox3, Me.TextBox4, Me.TextBox5, Me.TextBox6, 
Me.TextBox7, Me.TextBox8, Me.TextBox9, Me.TextBox10, Me.TextBox11, Me.TextBox12, Me.TextBox13, 
Me.TextBox14, Me.TextBox15, Me.TextBox16, Me.TextBox17, Me.TextBox18, Me.TextBox19, Me.TextBox20)
With ListBox1
    .AddItem
    For i = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)
        .List(.ListCount - 1, i) = arr1(i).Value
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of columns that one can add using the AddItem method is limited to 10 columns.  Try the following instead...

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    With Me.ListBox1
        If .ListCount = 0 Then
            GetFirstRow
        Else
            GetNextRow
        End If
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub GetFirstRow()

    Dim arr() As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    With Me.ListBox1
        ReDim arr(1 To 1, 1 To .ColumnCount)
    End With

    For i = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
        arr(1, i) = Me.Controls("TextBox" & i).Value
    Next i

    Me.ListBox1.list = arr()

End Sub

Private Sub GetNextRow()

    Dim arr() As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    With Me.ListBox1
        arr() = Application.Transpose(.list())
        ReDim Preserve arr(1 To UBound(arr, 1), 1 To UBound(arr, 2) + 1)
        For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
            arr(i, UBound(arr, 2)) = Me.Controls("TextBox" & i).Value
        Next i
    End With

    Me.ListBox1.list = Application.Transpose(arr())

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks Domenic  the  code works perfectly  I appreciate your assistance

Comment: but  i have a problem   it add data  in the same row in listbox  it should add the new data to next row in listbox

Comment: any help about my problem

Comment: thanks Domenic  more  again   and  i'm  sorry  about  not sure if  code completely works now  every thing is  all right   your code works very well