# ListBox Scroll Event on Form

Tags: excel, vba, forms, events, scroll

I have two listboxes side by side, on a form, which emulate an Excel screen with the left side frozen in place.
The first listbox will show the sales date and the customer name.
The second listbox will show all kinds of details, so it can be scrolled horizontally without the customer name getting out of sight.

I managed to make ListBox1.TopIndex = ListBox2.TopIndex. But that only happens when I click on it, selecting an item, or moving the mouse over it. In short, using whatever Event there is available to activate that line of command.

I need that to happen whenever the user scrolls the list box up or down but there is no Scroll Event.

Right now, when I scroll listbox2 down listbox1 stays still. When I click an item on listbox2, listbox1 refreshes and aligns with it.

Comment: Since you already realize there is no scroll event, you may want to consider re-thinking your design. There is probably a more standard way of doing what you are trying to do. Synching the scrolling between 2 listboxes is just not a supported standard. What about loading the second listbox when the selected item in the first listbox changes? What about using some sort of grid? Maybe some hidden columns in the first listbox?

Comment: Thinking about it some more - i think all you need is a single listbox that has multiple columns. Is there any reason that wouldn't work for your case?

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your ideas. Well, I actually need more then 10 columns, which isnt supported in one listbox. I'm actually trying to make the two listboxes look like one listbox. They are enclosed in tight frames and glued to each other, while the listbox 1 scroll bar is hidden by its frame. The frame is slightly shorter horizontally. So it just looks like 1 listbox for the user. I also need the first one or two columns to be always visible. I mean.. it would look perfect if I could make it work in a stable way.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61191102/8422953

Answer (score 1):

Windows API is still very useful in VBA, meeting needs in more complex projects. To get the scroll in the ListBox, use the following codes, for Excel 32bits. I only warn that the use of 'Windows hooks' can bring unexpected or unforeseen instabilities, being necessary to assess whether or not it is appropriate to use this resource in a given project.

The code that moves the selection in the ListBox is "MouseProc". The others deal with the intercepts of messages from/to Windows to the Userform/ListBox, as well as when to start or end these intercepts (Hook/Unhook).

```
'Put or edit these events on the UserForm:
 
Private Sub ListBox1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    fnHookListBoxScroll
End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Deactivate()
    fnUnhookListBoxScroll
End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    fnUnhookListBoxScroll
End Sub
'++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Put these codes on a standard module:

Option Explicit

Private Type POINTAPI
    X As Long
    Y As Long
End Type

Private Type MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT
    pt As POINTAPI
    hwnd As Long
    wHitTestCode As Long
    dwExtraInfo As Long
End Type

Private Declare Function GetWindowLong Lib "user32.dll" _
    Alias "GetWindowLongA" ( _
    ByVal hwnd As Long, _
    ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function SetWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" _
    Alias "SetWindowsHookExA" ( _
    ByVal idHook As Long, _
    ByVal lpfn As Long, _
    ByVal hmod As Long, _
    ByVal dwThreadId As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function CallNextHookEx Lib "user32" ( _
    ByVal hHook As Long, _
    ByVal nCode As Long, _
    ByVal wParam As Long, _
    lParam As Any) As Long

Private Declare Function UnhookWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" ( _
    ByVal hHook As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function PostMessage Lib "user32.dll" _
    Alias "PostMessageA" ( _
    ByVal hwnd As Long, _
    ByVal wMsg As Long, _
    ByVal wParam As Long, _
    ByVal lParam As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function WindowFromPoint Lib "user32" ( _
    ByVal xPoint As Long, _
    ByVal yPoint As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32.dll" ( _
    ByRef lpPoint As POINTAPI) As Long

Private Const WH_MOUSE_LL As Long = 14
Private Const WM_MOUSEWHEEL As Long = &H20A
Private Const HC_ACTION As Long = 0
Private Const GWL_HINSTANCE As Long = (-6)

Private Const WM_KEYDOWN As Long = &H100
Private Const WM_KEYUP As Long = &H101
Private Const VK_UP As Long = &H26
Private Const VK_DOWN As Long = &H28
Private Const WM_LBUTTONDOWN As Long = &H201

Private mLngMouseHook As Long
Private mListBoxHwnd As Long
Private mbHook As Boolean

Sub fnHookListBoxScroll()
    Dim lngAppInst As Long
    Dim hwndUnderCursor As Long
    Dim tPT As POINTAPI
    
    GetCursorPos tPT
    DoEvents
    hwndUnderCursor = WindowFromPoint(tPT.X, tPT.Y)
    DoEvents
    If mListBoxHwnd <> hwndUnderCursor Then
        fnUnhookListBoxScroll
        DoEvents
        mListBoxHwnd = hwndUnderCursor
        DoEvents
        lngAppInst = GetWindowLong(mListBoxHwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE)
        DoEvents
        PostMessage mListBoxHwnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 0&, 0&
        DoEvents
        If Not mbHook Then
            mLngMouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx( _
                WH_MOUSE_LL, AddressOf MouseProc, lngAppInst, 0)
            DoEvents
            mbHook = mLngMouseHook <> 0
            DoEvents
        End If
        DoEvents
    End If
    DoEvents
End Sub

Sub fnUnhookListBoxScroll()
    If mbHook Or mLngMouseHook = 0 Then
        UnhookWindowsHookEx mLngMouseHook
        mLngMouseHook = 0
        mListBoxHwnd = 0
        mbHook = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Function MouseProc( _
    ByVal nCode As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, _
    ByRef lParam As MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT) As Long
    On Error GoTo errH 'Resume Next
    If (nCode = HC_ACTION) Then
        If WindowFromPoint(lParam.pt.X, lParam.pt.Y) = mListBoxHwnd Then
            If wParam = WM_MOUSEWHEEL Then
                MouseProc = True
                If lParam.hwnd > 0 Then
                    PostMessage mListBoxHwnd, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_UP, 0
                    DoEvents
                Else
                    PostMessage mListBoxHwnd, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_DOWN, 0
                    DoEvents
                End If
                PostMessage mListBoxHwnd, WM_KEYUP, VK_UP, 0
                DoEvents
                Exit Function
            End If
        Else
            fnUnhookListBoxScroll
        End If
    End If
    MouseProc = CallNextHookEx( _
        mLngMouseHook, nCode, wParam, ByVal lParam)
    Exit Function
errH:
    fnUnhookListBoxScroll
End Function
```

*** Important: ***

If you're using Excel 64bit (under a 64 bit Windows), this is the right code to use:

Among other significant changes, not only to the 'Declares' but also to the code itself, note the drastic change of the POINTAPI Type. It was necessary to create a dedicated Function to pass the respective data correctly.

```
  'Put or edit these events on the UserForm:
    Option Explicit
    
    Private Sub ListBox1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal x As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
        fnHookListBoxScroll
    End Sub
    
    Private Sub UserForm_Deactivate()
        fnUnhookListBoxScroll
    End Sub
    
    Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
        fnUnhookListBoxScroll
    End Sub
    '++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    'Put these codes on a standard module:
    
    Option Explicit
    
    
    Public Type POINTAPI
        x As Long
        Y As Long
    End Type
    
    Private Type MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT
        pt As POINTAPI
        hwnd As Long
        wHitTestCode As Long
        dwExtraInfo As Long
    End Type
    
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowLong Lib "user32.dll" _
        Alias "GetWindowLongA" ( _
        ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, _
        ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
    
    Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" _
        Alias "SetWindowsHookExA" ( _
        ByVal idHook As Long, _
        ByVal lpfn As LongPtr, _
        ByVal hmod As LongPtr, _
        ByVal dwThreadId As Long) As LongPtr
    
    Declare PtrSafe Function CallNextHookEx Lib "user32" _
        ( _
        ByVal hHook As LongPtr, _
        ByVal ncode As Long, _
        ByVal wParam As LongPtr, _
        lParam As Any) As LongPtr
    
    Declare PtrSafe Function UnhookWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" ( _
        ByVal hhk As LongPtr) As Long
    
    Declare PtrSafe Function PostMessage Lib "user32" Alias _
        "PostMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, _
        ByVal wMsg As Long, _
        ByVal wParam As LongPtr, _
        ByVal lParam As LongPtr) As Long
    
    Declare PtrSafe Function WindowFromPoint Lib "user32" _
        ( _
        ByVal Point As LongLong) As LongPtr
    
    Declare PtrSafe Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32" _
        (lpPoint As POINTAPI) As Long
        
    Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" _
        Alias "RtlMoveMemory" ( _
        Destination As Any, _
        Source As Any, _
        ByVal Length As LongPtr)
    
    Private Const WH_MOUSE_LL As Long = 14
    Private Const WM_MOUSEWHEEL As Long = &H20A
    Private Const HC_ACTION As Long = 0
    Private Const GWL_HINSTANCE As Long = (-6)
    
    Private Const WM_KEYDOWN As Long = &H100
    Private Const WM_KEYUP As Long = &H101
    Private Const VK_UP As Long = &H26
    Private Const VK_DOWN As Long = &H28
    Private Const WM_LBUTTONDOWN As Long = &H201
    
    Private mLngMouseHook As LongPtr
    Private mListBoxHwnd As LongPtr
    Private mbHook As Boolean
    
    ' Copies a POINTAPI into a LongLong.  For an API requiring a ByVal POINTAPI parameter,
    ' this LongLong can be passed in instead.  Example API's include WindowFromPoint,
    ' ChildWindowFromPoint, ChildWindowFromPointEx, DragDetect, and MenuItemFromPoint.
    Function PointToLongLong(Point As POINTAPI) As LongLong
        Dim ll As LongLong
        Dim cbLongLong As LongPtr
        
        cbLongLong = LenB(ll)
        
        ' make sure the contents will fit
        If LenB(Point) = cbLongLong Then
            CopyMemory ll, Point, cbLongLong
        End If
        
        PointToLongLong = ll
    End Function
    
    Sub fnHookListBoxScroll()
        Dim lngAppInst As Long
        Dim hwndUnderCursor As LongPtr
        Dim tPT As POINTAPI
        
        GetCursorPos tPT
        DoEvents
        hwndUnderCursor = WindowFromPoint(PointToLongLong(tPT))
        DoEvents
        If mListBoxHwnd <> hwndUnderCursor Then
            fnUnhookListBoxScroll
            DoEvents
            mListBoxHwnd = hwndUnderCursor
            DoEvents
            lngAppInst = GetWindowLong(mListBoxHwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE)
            DoEvents
            PostMessage mListBoxHwnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 0&, 0&
            DoEvents
            If Not mbHook Then
                mLngMouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx( _
                    WH_MOUSE_LL, AddressOf MouseProc, lngAppInst, 0)
                DoEvents
                mbHook = mLngMouseHook <> 0
                DoEvents
            End If
            DoEvents
        End If
        DoEvents
    End Sub
    
    Sub fnUnhookListBoxScroll()
        If mbHook Or mLngMouseHook = 0 Then
            UnhookWindowsHookEx mLngMouseHook
            mLngMouseHook = 0
            mListBoxHwnd = 0
            mbHook = False
        End If
    End Sub
    
    Private Function MouseProc( _
        ByVal ncode As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, _
        ByRef lParam As MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT) As LongPtr
        On Error GoTo errH 'Resume Next
        If (ncode = HC_ACTION) Then
            If WindowFromPoint(PointToLongLong(lParam.pt)) = mListBoxHwnd Then
                If wParam = WM_MOUSEWHEEL Then
                    MouseProc = True
                    If lParam.hwnd > 0 Then
                        PostMessage mListBoxHwnd, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_UP, 0
                        DoEvents
                    Else
                        PostMessage mListBoxHwnd, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_DOWN, 0
                        DoEvents
                    End If
                    PostMessage mListBoxHwnd, WM_KEYUP, VK_UP, 0
                    DoEvents
                    Exit Function
                End If
            Else
                fnUnhookListBoxScroll
            End If
        End If
        MouseProc = CallNextHookEx( _
            mLngMouseHook, ncode, wParam, ByVal lParam)
        Exit Function
    errH:
        fnUnhookListBoxScroll
    End Function
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answering. I tried pasting it into a regular module, but the lines that begin with *Private Declare Function* are red. It's being marked as if there's something wrong with it. Any idea why?

Comment: As I mentioned, this code works on Excel 32bits. I've a copy of Excel 64bits and will adapt it as soon as possible.

Comment: Hi again. Just tried it. Like you said, no more red lines. But, when I mouse over listbox1, excel gives me a "Automation Error. Exception" and closes. Any ideas?
By the way... I thought I knew something about vba, but jesus... the solution looks so complex. I guess using windows API looks scary for me.

Comment: Well, this is working on Win10 + XL64bit. Did you paste the codes in the right places? Maybe you have to check some configuration at the Trust Center, mostly related to macro execution/permission. Windows API are complements to the VBA, as, say, PowerQuery, Add-Ins, etc are to the Excel front-end. Knowing VBA it's fine and you're in the right way.

Comment: This is a perfect answer for 64 bit. You're awesome @ALeXceL

Answer (score 0):

A simple option here (and yet something I didn't immediately think of when I had this same question) is to use a separate ScrollBar control where its events connect to both ListBox controls.

You have to sort out how to connect everything, depending possibly on whether the list boxes will show a set number of items or be expandable.  However, it has all the events.